# How to add inside Laravel (Blade engine?)

Tags: laravel, parameters, datatables, routes, laravel-blade

ROUTE:

```
Route::get('usuario/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'Admin\UserController@edit']);
```

if it brings me the right id (data.id):

```
<a href="users.edit/' + data.id + '"  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

it does not bring me the right id:

```
<a href="{{ route('users.edit','+data.id+') }}"  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

How to add inside Laravel (Blade engine?) 
Concatenation doesn't work

CODE:
{data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '';
                        //return '';
                        }
                    }

Comment: What is `data.id`?  It looks like JS but you can't just go in and out of HTML like that using JS.

Comment: php is ran server side ... javascript is ran client side .. they don't directly interact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're literally passing: `+data.id+` as your argument. Because PHP cannot be interpreted on the client side, you can only alias it ahead of time and modify it later:

```
let route = '{{ route('users.edit', '%DATA_ID%') }}'
```

Add a class to the anchor link for reference:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary edit-link"...
```

Then select it and update the route later:

```
document.querySelector('a.edit-link').href = route.replace('%DATA_ID%', data.id)
```

Or if you've got `$data` as an stdClass coming back from Laravel:

```
<a href="{{ route('users.edit', $data->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
```

Comment: {data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
      return '<a href="users.edit/' + data.id + '"  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>';
      //return '<a href="{{ route('users.edit', '+data.id+') }}"  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>';
      }
     }

Comment: Then you can alias it in the blade view just like I showed in my example to achieve this and use `<a href="'+route.replace('%DATA_ID%', data.id) +'"..`